# How to POST parameters and body in HttpURLConnection

Tags: java

How do I do both at the same time?

The parameters are just query string parameters. The body is json.

```
 connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
 connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
 connection.setDoOutput(true);
 connection.getOutputStream().write(parameters);
 connection.getOutputStream().write(sqlDatabase.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

sqlDatabase is a JsonObject, while parameters is just a byte[];

Comment: If they're query string parameters, write them to the URL, not to the body.

Comment: In a standard POST request, the parameters *are* the request body.  You could consider defining a new request parameter to carry the extra data.

Comment: I thought I can only do that if it was GET?

Comment: @JohnBollinger How do I define a new request?

Comment: By "define a new request parameter" I just mean you choose a name not already in use, and write it, with the value, into the request body along with all the others.  The server has to cooperate, of course, since it will need to obtain the data via the new parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, this depends on the server which is interpreting your POST request.  But it seems to me you would want to treat your data like an HTML form which includes a file.

Such a form POSTs its data as a multipart/form-data body.  Each parameter, whether a query parameter or file data, is a separate part in the multipart body.  The [HTML 4 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2) and [RFC 2388](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2388) describe this in detail.

Creating a multipart body can be done with the [JavaMail](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/) library:

```
List<BodyPart> partList = new ArrayList<>();
ParameterList dispositionParams = new ParameterList();

for (String queryParam : parameters.split("&")) {
    String[] nameAndValue = queryParam.split("=", 2);
    String name = nameAndValue[0];
    String value = nameAndValue[1];

    name = URLDecoder.decode(name, "UTF-8");
    value = URLDecoder.decode(value, "UTF-8");

    dispositionParams.set("name", name);
    ContentDisposition disposition =
        new ContentDisposition("form-data", dispositionParams);

    MimeBodyPart part = new MimeBodyPart();
    part.setDisposition(disposition.toString());
    part.setText(value);
    partList.add(part);
}

dispositionParams.set("database", name);
ContentDisposition disposition =
    new ContentDisposition("form-data", dispositionParams);

MimeBodyPart dbPart = new MimeBodyPart();
dbPart.setDisposition(disposition.toString());
dbPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(
    new ByteArrayDataSource(sqlDatabase.toString(), "application/json")));
partList.add(dbPart);

BodyPart[] parts = partList.toArray(new BodyPart[0]);

Multipart body = new MimeMultipart("form-data", parts);

connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", body.getContentType());
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
connection.setDoOutput(true);
body.writeTo(connection.getOutputStream());
```